# Sandbox: Request does not get canceled when no drivers available

Tags: uber-api

Current behavior on sandbox:

- Create ride request (drivers available)
- While status is `processing`, set drivers not available
- Ride request status changes to `no_drivers_available` as expected
- Set drivers back to available
- Previous ride request is back to `processing`

I would be expecting the request to not go back to `processing` and rather stay on `no_drivers_available`. Is this a bug or is that your defined behavior? If so, could you provide more explanation?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about following statement: "I would be expecting the request to not go back to pending and rather stay on no_drivers_available" ? If you look Uber documentation about Life cycle of a Ride Request : [link](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/best-practices#life-cycle-of-a-ride-request) you will see there is no pending state.

Comment: I meant `processing` (just edited). Very sorry about the mistake. Question should make more sense now. 
So basically, why is request going back to `processing` after being `no_drivers_available`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is valid ride request with **"processing"** status - and product that was used to create this request was modified and set **drivers_available** to false, ride requests will terminate with the status **"no_drivers_available"**. If product gets modified again and set **drivers_available** to **true** - ride request status will change to **"processing"** again - and closest available driver will be able to accept this request. So there is no "bug" in this flow - and this is expected behavior.